# Getting 404 not found Laravel POST request

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am making a post request in my form

```
 <form action="/confirmation" method="POST"> 
      {{ csrf_field() }}
      <input type="text" name="confirmationcode" required>
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
 </form>
```

My route

```
Route::post('/confirmation', 'bookController@confirmation');
```

My `bookController`

```
public function confirmation() 
{
    $code = request('confirmationcode');
    dd($code);
}
```

I am getting 404 in my console

```
POST http://127.0.0.8000/confirmation 404 (Not Found)
```

And `Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.` in my browser

I just cannot seem to figure out what is wrong, I wonder if another pair of eyes can help me.

Comment: You haven't included a closing tag for you form, </form>. Has it just been cropped out?

Comment: Are you using php artisan serve to run your project locally? http://127.0.0.1000 is not the usual ip

Comment: there is a closing form tag and i am using php artisan serve

Comment: Which routes file have you registered the route in? What is shown when you run `php artisan route:list`

Comment: You should be using `{{ url("/confirmation") }}` to ensure Laravel creates the URL correctly (in the cases you're serving the framework in a subfolder.

Comment: Could you add the method that calls your form?

Answer (score 4):

The same thing happened to me, everything was ok, I tried to refresh the cache and it worked, you can try the following commands in the terminal

```
php artisan optimize
php artisan route:cache
php artisan view:clear
php artisan config:cache
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public function confirmation(Request $request) 
{
    $code = $request->confirmationcode;
    dd($code);
}
```

Comment: `$request` and `request()` is the same, doesn't make a difference

Comment: This should be $request->input(‘confirmation’)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `$code` is set

Try this on your controller

```
public function confirmation()
{
    if(isset($code))
    {
    $code = request('confirmationcode');
    dd($code)
    }
    dd('fail');
}
```

If the `$code` is set then only try to `dd($code)` if that does not work try `if(!empty($code))`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the url() helper function

```
<form action="{{url('confirmation')}}" method="POST">
```